# Add multidimensional array to html table in Powershell

Tags: html, arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I have 2D array `$dates` with 2 columns and multiple rows for example:

```
$dates[0][0] = 2016.07.20
$dates[0][1] = 1
$dates[1][0] = 2016.08.19
$dates[1][1] = 6
...
```

I need to add this array to html output as table.
For example I have style of html table:

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"
```

When i use:

```
$dates | Select @{expression={$_}}| ConvertTo-HTML -head $a | out-file "C:\Test.htm"
```

I get this output, where they are in the same column:

```
<tr><td>2016.07.20 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2016.08.19 6</td></tr>
<tr><td>2016.08.20 6</td></tr>
```

I need to have values be in different columns:

```
<tr><td>2016.07.20</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2016.08.19</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>2016.08.20</td><td>6</td></tr>
```

Unfortunately I was unable to find examples how to fix that. 
Please can anyone help?
How I can add values in different columns?

Comment: Whats wrong with the top results when googling your question title? Like [PowerShell Build a 2D HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26381635) or [Powershell: Display array-members in ConvertTo-HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6533985)

Comment: What kinds of "columns" do the objects in `$dates` have? Is it just space-separated strings? Objects from a csv?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - it is just 2-dimensional array of strings.

Comment: @wOxxOm in both these examples there are "-Header 'OU',..." or "select ComputerName -ExpandProperty Disks".
But my array is pretty simple, no Headers, all items are like that:
$dates[0][0] = 2016.07.20 ;
$dates[0][1] = 1 ;
$dates[1][0] = 2016.08.19 ;
$dates[1][1] = 6
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the array manually:

```
'<tr>' + (
    ($dates | %{
        '<td>' + ($_ -join '</td><td>') + '</td>'
    }) -join "</tr>`n<tr>"
) + '</tr>'
```